# Get a number from a promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, promise

I have:

```
 getZoom(): Promise<number> {
    return this._googleMapsApi.getMap().then((map:google.maps.Map) => map.getZoom());
}
```

I would like to check the zoom level:

```
private onStartZoomEvent() {
    console.log('on start zoom');
    if (this._mapController.getZoom().valueOf() !== 12) {
    this.disableGeolocationButton();
    this._eventAggregator.trigger(this.disableGeolocation);
     }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of a promise is you can't get the value synchronously. When you call getZoom(), it's returning a promise. Then, you attempt to call valueOf() on that Promise; the method doesn't exist, and the promise isn't fulfilled yet.

It should look something like this:

```
private onStartZoomEvent() {
    console.log('on start zoom');
    this._mapController.getZoom()
        .then((zoom) => {
            if (zoom.valueOf() !== 12) {
            this.disableGeolocationButton();
            this._eventAggregator.trigger(this.disableGeolocation);
        });
    }
}
```